# How to use grep to detect if specific text is found inside a folder?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to get an exit code only if a specific text is found in a set of log file.

If no matches are found, or no files are present the command should pass successfully.

Grep should be silent, as I don't want to see the matches. I only want to know if the pattern was found (using exit code).

Somehow it seems that if use quiet mode to silence grep, the result code will always be success.

Comment: `grep --silent hm /etc/passwd` returns `1`, as expected. If that's not working for you, you can always discard stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
mkdir _ ; cd _ ; touch a ; echo b > b
grep -q c * || echo $?
1
```

0 means success, 1 means no matches. In a condition, you don't need the $?, you can use the command directly:

```
if grep -q c * ; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to just use `! grep ... >/dev/null`.

Comment: `0` status is success, unlike in languages like `C`. Isn't that the source of your confusion? Otherwise what is the reason for `!` ?